# Framework / Design pattern for business rule validation

Tags: java, design-patterns, frameworks

What kind of framework / design pattern should I use for application which possibly has 1000 over biz rule validations?

The type of systems I am working on consist of lots of input forms which allow users to enter. Each input form has different sections.

i.e. Form A has Section A/B/C/D. Form B has section B/C/D

Some of these biz rule validation are common to both forms, I am looking at a approach to reuse the rules as well.

How do I build a robust business rule validation framework?

Comment: It is too broad a question.. What have you considered?

Comment: 1000 validations or 1000 rules? How complex are the rules? How frequently do they change? How quickly do they need to change? Are changes retroactive?

Comment: combinations of rules and validation. they hardly change, for each rule i need to return an error message to the users.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- [drools](/questions/tagged/drools) framework is specifically designed to evaluate business rules
- [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) framework allows writing beans using dynamic languages like [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy) and [jruby](/questions/tagged/jruby). You can easily plug [JavaScript](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2010/09/javascript-dynamic-language-support-in.html)
- [strategy design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) seems like a good fit: implement each rule as a separate strategy and run them one after another.
- similar [chain of responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern can be used: each rule either fails or succeeds and passes control to next rule

Comment: When you mention "implement each rule as a separate strategy" hopefully you're not suggesting a strategy class for each of the 1000 validations mentioned by the OP. That would be quite a class explosion, right? Or maybe instead you are referring to a separate class instance per rule.

Comment: @Brady: actually I **do** mean a separate class for a rule. Each rule can then have a name, be unit tested and placed in meaningful package. Also probably some rules can be generified so that one class with different setup can be used for several rules. Finally classes are cheap (wrt. lines of code) in languages like [tag:scala] and [tag:groovy]. And what is the alternative? A single class with thousands of lines of rules code (assuming one rule can fit in 1-2 lines?)

Comment: Tomasz, I see your point, I would think that a combination of what you mention would be best, especially generalizing many rules with one or a few classes. Of course I wouldnt want to see one messy class for all, but on the flip-side I wouldnt think that 1000s of classes would be optimal either.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz 1000 classes dont look like a possible attempt to resolve such issues?

Comment: @optimus: I believe a lot of these rules could be reused so you'll end up with dozens, maybe hundred parametrizable rules you can build together.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz how can the rules been customized?

Comment: @optimus: you mean classes with rules? By passing different arguments to the constructor? E.g. `Between` rule taking `min`/`max` values.

Answer (score 6):

A good pattern to implement business rules is the [Specification pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern). It's a combination of *Strategy*, *Composite* and *Interpreter* that can make for parameterized and easily combinable rules. Be sure to also look at the [original paper (pdf)](http://www.martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf) by Fowler and Evans, and take a look at the book **Domain Driven Design** if you can.

Comment: For every rule, I need to return a corresponding error message. How can the Specification Pattern help?

Comment: Error messages can also be returned from the specification method, along with a success flag. You can package them in a kind of "operation result" class and return it from the `isSatisfied` method.

Comment: Create another OperationResult class which probably has an list which contains all the appropriate message?

Comment: Yes, that class encapsulates the result of the business rules logic; wheter it was successful and all its result messages.

Comment: for every rule i will have a specification class?

Comment: For every _unique_ rule. Some rules might be generic enough that they can be parameterized to serve as a template for _many_ rules.